# Not receiving any reputation change notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, notifications

I can't receive any Notification about reputation change.

This is how my notification tab looks like right now:

[image]

This is my actual reputation tab:

[image]

As you can see, the rep gained today is not visible in the notification bar nor did I receive any notification about them.

This does not appear to be a local cache issue on one device as I can reproduce this on my mac as well:

[image]

My client config are:

1. Google Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) using Windows 8.1
2. Google Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) using macOS Sierra 10.12.3

This has been [reported on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293094/why-does-the-reputation-dropdown-not-show-this-upvote) already by Mithrandir.

**EDIT**

[Oded♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) has [confirmed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346191/is-the-rep-widget-broken-again#comment460713_346191) that this is indeed a bug and SE teams are working on it:

> We are aware of things being broken - the process that syncs
>   reputation (and other things) across the network is backed up. We are
>   working on fixing it.

The Process seems to be up (Although not working correctly as reported by a number of users) again. [Quoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293120/307083) Patrick Hoffman:

> Yes. The process is up and running again. Reputation changes are
>   finding their way to us.
>
> Sometimes there is a small delay though in the dropdown and the green
>   notification. And the number doesn't always correspond with the
>   highlighted post in the dropdown. I guess that will be resolved
>   eventually.

I did receive a collective rep change notification for today  as well.

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Oded just provided an answer and confirmed that this has been resolved.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293094/why-does-the-reputation-dropdown-not-show-this-upvote

Comment: How many times is this going to be reported? o_o

Comment: @Mithrandir Yours is actually the proper place to go, as this appears to be impacting whole network, MSE is the right place for report. Guess we should leave it here so that other SF&F members don't re-report it once they notice it.

Comment: @Mithrandir Hopefully not as many times as there are users who're interested in rep :-P

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this, I was curious what was up as well.

Comment: Sadly, I've had no rep, so no notifications :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue with some of the reputation messages going to the achievements drop down - the initial fix helped, but did not resolve the root issue, which is why you have seen the issue come back.

We have fixed the root issue and things are back to normal.

Sorry for the inconvenience.